# Identity Operator / Comparison without Implicit Type Conversion

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

When using PowerShell, occasionally we compare objects of different types.  A common scenario being `$int -eq $bool` (i.e. where `0 -eq $false`, `0 -ne $true`, and any non-zero value only equals true, but not false).

Mostly that's a good thing; sometimes it's a pain (e.g. if I'm looking for all properties on an object which have value `1`, but I don't want all those which have value `$true`).

**Question**

Is there an operator which performs this comparison without conversion; i.e. which essentially does the same as JavaScript's identity operator (`===`);?

**Bonus Question**

If there is such an operator, is there any tolerance?  i.e. whilst I don't want to treat `1` and `true` as being identical, it would (sometimes) be helpful if I could treat `[int]1` and `[long]1` as though they are.

Comment: `[Object]::Equals($a, $b)`

Comment: @PetSerAl; of course!  Thank-you.

Comment: @PetSerAl Please post this as answer. Will be helpful for others as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PowerShell do not offer such operator directly, but you can use standard .NET method [`[Object]::Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) to do such comparison.

Note:
It allows to types to implement they own equality comparison by overriding virtual [`Object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method, thus it possible to have some weird behavior, if some custom type implement it improperly. But all standard .NET types should fine and consider themselves equals only to the instance of the same type.